# Target a specific Widget with Placement.info in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. In a Page I have lets say four `Html widget`, I want to place one of these Html Widgets in a `local zone`.

I used `Shape Tracing Tool` to get the name of the shape of this specific `Html widget` But all of these four Widgets have Same the name in `Shape Tracing Tool`.

So how can I target only one of them?

Comment: Dear, You can't ordering widgets in layout zones through 'Placement.info' file, please explain more what you want to do? are you want to display your widget inside another shape?

Comment: Thanks for comment, Oh didn't know that, I want to display widget somewhere inside this alternate "Content-ProjectionPage-url-faq.cshtml"

Comment: You should create a new layout zone specifically for this widget, add you widget through Orchard dashboard to this zone, then display this zone inside your shape, without displaying your zone in layout.cshtml, if this is what you want I can provide you with some code snippet?

Comment: I cant display this new Layout zone in the Layout.cshtml, because I want it somewehre inside the Content Layout Zone, Is this possible this way? Or I guess I need to create an New Layout.cshtml file Alternate for this url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you should add new zone to `Theme.txt`:

```
Zones: MyCustomZone, .., .., ..
```

then after adding your widget to this zone through Orchard dashboard, you can display this zone `MyCustomZone`, anywhere you want in your system, just using the following line:

```cs
@Display(WorkContext.Layout.MyCustomZone)
```

Note: you don't need to render it in your layout if this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Widget Alternates" module and alternates with widget name will appear.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Its already enabled, but alternates with widget name not appearing, I updated the question and put the alternates its showing

Comment: If you create a Widget-Name-YourWidgetNameHere.cshtml view in your theme with just a div inside, does it work? (ps: restart your site)

Comment: I checked, my widget had no Name, I edited it and gave it a name, and shape Tracing showing me two more Alternate, I can use this ~/Themes/Webtarash.Porto/Views/Widget-Name-FAQDesc.cshtml and it works

Comment: I'm gonna use this in placement.info, so the shape name will be some thing like this "Widget_Name_FAQDesc" ?

Comment: I checked "Widget_Name_FAQDesc" didn't work in placement.info

Comment: The name of the attribute can be any shape name (but not an alternate name; use Match to specialize placement instead).

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want this Widget somewhere in middle of the ContentZone, So I put this widget in ContentZone and with placement.info I place it in a local zone that I display in this Alternate "Content-ProjectionPage-url-faq.cshtml"

Comment: I guess my other option is to Create a new alternate Layout and create a new Zone for this

Comment: Try this, but not sure:     <Match ContentType="Widget"><Place Parts_Common_Body="Content:5;Alternate=Widget_Name_FAQDesc"/></Match>

Comment: Thanks, nah didn't work, but I'll work on it and tell u the result

Comment: Turned out we cant place widgets with placement.info